# jqPlot BarRenderer rendering a line graph instead of a bar graph

Tags: javascript, canvas, jqplot

I'm trying to graph a histogram of 1 series with 100 inputs. However, jqPlot keeps rendering my data as a line graph when I specify it to render a bar graph instead. My code is a modified version of the bar graph examples.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/src/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
            var hits = [123, 54, 897, ...]

            var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [hits], {
                    seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
                    },
                        series:[ {label:'Hits'} ],

            legend: {
                    show: true,
                            placement: 'outsideGrid'
                            },
                        axes: {
                              xaxis: {
                        autoscale: true,
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                numberTicks: 4,
                                tickInterval: 25
                                },
                            yaxis: {
                        autoscale: true
                        }
                    }
                });
                });
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebug console to know if all your jqplot sources are well imported? Because your code is working find : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/uSuU5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `seriesDefaults` options to your jqplot options :

```
seriesDefaults: {
  renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
  rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
}
```

Comment: I already set the seriesDefaults in my source code above. I also added the fillToZero option but it didn't change the graph at all.

Comment: It was an include problem as per your comment on my OP. Thanks for catching that!